# Displaying Jira issues using Issue Navigator

Tags: jira, jql

Below is simple Jira JQL search statement:

```
JqlQueryBuilder builder = JqlQueryBuilder.newBuilder();
builder.where().assignee().in("Dylan").and().unresolved();


Query query = builder.buildQuery();
```

Then we have search results:

```
SearchResults results = searchService.search(authenticationContext.getUser(),
            query, PagerFilter.getUnlimitedFilter());


List<Issue> issues = results.getIssues();
```

**Problem**: I need to find issues, filter them using several criteria and show results to the user using standard Jira Issue Navigator window (I don't want to create my own velocity template for it). I know, that it is possible to link JQL query string safely to an existing URL that points at the Issue Navigator. The main problem is that I have to compare two date fields of the issue (due date and resolution) and such comparison can't be done with JQL. So, I can't write query entirely with JQL. I have to mix JQL with standard Java (for date comparison, which is no problem at all).

So, my **MAIN QUESTION** is this: then I have a list of issues `List issues = results.getIssues()`, is it possible to display them using Issue Navigator? And how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the `List issues` you can create an array of Strings with the same size, and save all issues keys into this query result. Than, you can create a filter of the sort:

```
issueKey in (ABC-1,ABC-2,ABC-3,...)
```

or via URL:

```
https://your.jira.com/secure/IssueNavigator!executeAdvanced.jspa?jqlQuery=issuekey+in+%28%22ABC-1%22%2C%22ABC-2%22%29&runQuery=true&clear=true
```

Having said that, I'm not so sure you can't find an easier solution using a JQL query, what is it that you are trying to achieve?  The basic JQL gives some date-search abilities:

```
resolutionDate < "2013/01/01" and duedate < now()
```

Have a look at [JIRA's Advanced Searching](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching#AdvancedSearching-IssueKey) for more information.

If the standard JQL isn't enough, check out existing plugins, such as [JQL Tricks Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.j-tricks.jql-plugin). Another option might be to create your own JQL search, check [Adding a JQL Function to JIRA](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Plugin+Tutorial+-+Adding+a+JQL+Function+to+JIRA) for more info about this solution.

Let me know if you need help and good luck!

Comment: I think I'd write a new JQL function, either as a plugin or using the Script Runner plugin.

Comment: Thank you for showing me the correct direction! I solved my problem by writing a new custom JQL function as a plugin, put all needed Java logic in it and then called this new function like: builder.where().issue().inFunc("myFunctionName"); Then: Query query = builder.buildQuery(); String queryString = query.getQueryString(); Then I appended this queryString to an existing URL that points to the Issue Navigator. In my situation this URL was used in the image map functionality of charting plugin, where user clicks some area on chart and gets appropriate issues.