# Displaying Many Jira issues using Issue Navigator

Tags: post, cookies, jira, jira-plugin

[My question is similar to "Displaying Jira issues using Issue Navigator"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14945588/displaying-jira-issues-using-issue-navigator) But my concern is that sometimes my list of issues is quite long and providing the user with a link to the Issue Navigator only works if my link is shorter than the max length of URLs.

Is there another way? Cookies? POST data? Perhaps programmatically creating and sharing a filter on the fly, and returning a link to the Issue Navigator that uses this filter? (But at some point I'd want to delete these filters so I don't have so many lying around.)

I do have the JQL query for getting the same list of issues, but it takes a very (very) long time to run and my code has already done the work of finding out what the result is -- I don't want the user to wait twice for the same thing (once while I'm generating my snazzy graphical servlet view and a second time when they want to see the same results in the Issue Navigator).

Comment: Does your current code run on the same server as JIRA? And if so, would you be open to developing a JIRA plugin to help get the issue list into JIRA?

Comment: (Or do you mean that you are already developing a JIRA plugin, you already have the list of issues available within your plugin's code, and you just need a way to get them over to the issue navigator?)

Comment: The latter - my plugin has the list of issues and I'd like to see the same list in the Issue Navigator.

Comment: The best would be to bring up the list in Issue Navigator without having to run the query **and** populate the search field with the JQL query... in other words, magic. Is this possible with cookies or POST data or someother mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to implement this is to ensure that the list of issues is cached somewhere within one of your application components. Each separate list of issues should be identified by its own unique ID (the `magicKey` below) that you define yourself.

You would then write your own JQL function that looks up your pre-calculated list of issues by that magic key, which then converts the list of issues into the format that the Issue Navigator requires.

The buildUriEncodedJqlQuery() method can be used to create such an example JQL query dynamically. For example, if the magic key is 1234, it would yield this JQL query: `issue in myJqlFunction(1234)`.

You'd then feed the user a URL that looks like this:

```
String url = "/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?mode=hide&reset=true&jqlQuery=" + MyJqlFunction.buildUriEncodedJqlQuery(magicKey);
```

The end result is that the user will be placed in the Issue Navigator looking at exactly the list of issues your code has provided.

This code also specifically prevents the user from saving your JQL function as part of a saved filter, since it's assumed that the issue cache in your application will not be permanent. If that's not correct, you will want to empty out the sanitiseOperand part.

In atlassian-plugins.xml:

```
<jql-function key="myJqlFunction" name="My JQL Function" 
              class="com.mycompany.MyJqlFunction">
</jql-function>
```

JQL function:

```
import com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.api.User;
import com.atlassian.jira.JiraDataType;
import com.atlassian.jira.JiraDataTypes;
import com.atlassian.jira.jql.operand.QueryLiteral;
import com.atlassian.jira.jql.query.QueryCreationContext;
import com.atlassian.jira.plugin.jql.function.ClauseSanitisingJqlFunction;
import com.atlassian.jira.plugin.jql.function.JqlFunction;
import com.atlassian.jira.plugin.jql.function.JqlFunctionModuleDescriptor;
import com.atlassian.jira.util.MessageSet;
import com.atlassian.jira.util.MessageSetImpl;
import com.atlassian.jira.util.NotNull;
import com.atlassian.query.clause.TerminalClause;
import com.atlassian.query.operand.FunctionOperand;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MyJqlFunction implements JqlFunction, ClauseSanitisingJqlFunction
{
    private static final String JQL_FUNCTION_NAME = "myJqlFunctionName";
    private static final int JQL_FUNCTION_MIN_ARG_COUNT = 1;
    private static final int JQL_FUNCTION_MAGIC_KEY_INDEX = 0;

    public MyJqlFunction()
    {
        // inject your app's other components here
    }

    @Override
    public void init(@NotNull JqlFunctionModuleDescriptor moduleDescriptor)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public JiraDataType getDataType()
    {
        return JiraDataTypes.ISSUE;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFunctionName()
    {
        return JQL_FUNCTION_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public int getMinimumNumberOfExpectedArguments()
    {
        return JQL_FUNCTION_MIN_ARG_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isList()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * This function generates a URL-escaped JQL query that corresponds to the supplied magic key.
     * 
     * @param magicKey
     * @return
     */
    public static String buildUriEncodedJqlQuery(String magicKey)
    {
        return "issue%20in%20" + JQL_FUNCTION_NAME + "(%22"
                + magicKey + "%22%)";
    }

    @Override
    public List<QueryLiteral> getValues(@NotNull QueryCreationContext queryCreationContext,
                                        @NotNull FunctionOperand operand,
                                        @NotNull TerminalClause terminalClause)
    {
        User searchUser = queryCreationContext.getUser();

        MessageSet messages = new MessageSetImpl();

        List<QueryLiteral> values = internalGetValues(searchUser,
                operand,
                terminalClause,
                messages,
                !queryCreationContext.isSecurityOverriden());

        return values;
    }


    private List<QueryLiteral> internalGetValues(@NotNull User searchUser,
                                                 @NotNull FunctionOperand operand,
                                                 @NotNull TerminalClause terminalClause,
                                                 @NotNull MessageSet messages,
                                                 @NotNull Boolean checkSecurity)
    {
        List<QueryLiteral> result = new ArrayList<QueryLiteral>();

        if (searchUser==null)
        {
            // handle anon user
        }

        List<String> args = operand.getArgs();

        if (wasSanitised(args))
        {
            messages.addErrorMessage("this function can't be used as part of a saved filter etc");
            return result;
        }

        if (args.size() < getMinimumNumberOfExpectedArguments())
        {
            messages.addErrorMessage("too few arguments, etc");
            return result;
        }

        final String magicKey = args.get(JQL_FUNCTION_MAGIC_KEY_INDEX);


        // You need to implement this part yourself! This is where you use the supplied
        // magicKey to fetch a list of issues from your own internal data source.

        List<String> myIssueKeys = myCache.get(magicKey);

        for (String id : myIssueKeys)
        {
            result.add(new QueryLiteral(operand, id));
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public MessageSet validate(User searcher, @NotNull FunctionOperand operand, @NotNull TerminalClause terminalClause)
    {
        MessageSet messages = new MessageSetImpl();
        internalGetValues(searcher, operand, terminalClause, messages, true);
        return messages;
    }

    @Override
    public FunctionOperand sanitiseOperand(User paramUser, @NotNull FunctionOperand operand)
    {
        // prevent the user from saving this as a filter, since the results are presumed to be dynamic

        return new FunctionOperand(operand.getName(), Arrays.asList(""));
    }

    private boolean wasSanitised(List<String> args)
    {
        return (args.size() == 0 || args.get(JQL_FUNCTION_MAGIC_KEY_INDEX).isEmpty());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Blown away a la the Maxell ad from the '70s https://www.google.com/search?q=maxell+ad+blown+away&safe=active&tbm=isch